# Workaround for post already in use spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am using spring-boot and every time if i run my project again then it throws an error

```
Port already in use
```

So i have to stop java.exe from task manager everytime.

Is there any workaround for this?

I am already using dev tools in case somebody suggests that answer.
Thanks!!

Comment: How do you run the project? mvn spring-boot:run?

Comment: Yes I run it like this only

Comment: Then terminating the command should release the port. Otherwise I don't know :(